# how do i get the numeric representation of a character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numeric, alphabet

I'd like to get a javascript numeric representation for a letter to do some relative manipulation i.e. in pseudocode to conduct an operation like 'a'.getNumberRep - 'b'.getNumberRep.

Best way to do this in js?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "numeric representation" ? Transforming "1" to 1 ? Unicode value ? Alphabetic value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'a'.charCodeAt(0) - 'b'.charCodeAt(0)
```